# UISwipeGestureRecognizer for SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit, arkit, scnnode

Is there something like a UISwipeGestureRecognizer for SceneKit? Suppose I want to swipe on a SCNNode, is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it’s called UISwipeGestureRecognizer :) Quite a few questions and answers at SO cover transforming nodes based on gesture input already. Search for unprojectPoint, a SCNView method to convert 2D screen coordinates to 3D coordinates. Basically you update the SCNNode.position based on the location/transform of the gesture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I'm confused a little. I have a SCNNode already in my code, how do I make it swipe-able for use in ARKit? Is there something to do with UITouch?

Comment: Hi Amit, can you provide us some code of your SCNNode and ViewController so I could embed the UISwipeGestureRecoginizer inside

Comment: Did you find any solution around it?